# Pdf to Swf conversion using Java

Tags: java, pdf, flash

Does anybody know a Java tool that can convert a pdf file to a swf file ?

To clarify, we are building a site to generate photo albums. The photo album editor is written in Flash (ActionScript 3.0) and then on the back-end is written in Java and it generates a pdf for the album. The problem is having two rendering engines (Flash for client side, and Java on the server) and their output must be identical. 
We think that having the back-end generate a pdf file and then converting it to swf gives the highest fidelity, so that's why this conversion tool is needed. However, if people have other solutions these are welcomed as well.

Comment: What do you mean?  PDF is a form of electronic document. Flash is something entirely different.

Comment: Anyway, why you want it in java ... There are many tools can be used to convert pdf to flash, just google it.

Comment: I believe the author needs a programmatic way of converting an in memory PDF to a SWF file to be served back to a flash client.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that could be used:
- The server generates the pdf
- The server [launches](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html) the conversion program (for instance [this one](http://www.swftools.org/))
- The client uses the flash file

Comment: I did it once, but the other way round. I.e. a C++ program launching a java gui. +1 for the java launch. Didn't know it was possible.